# fatal: [cor-001]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "junos-eznc (aka PyEZ) >= 2.1.7 is required for this module. However, junos-eznc does not a

Tags: python, ansible, juniper, pyez

I am getting this error when trying to run my playbook even though I have already installed pyEZ.
Can anyone please help me to fix it?

> MCBOOK:~ user2018$ ansible-playbook simpletest.yml
>
> [DEPRECATION WARNING]: [defaults]hostfile option, The key is
>   misleading as it can also be a list of hosts, a directory or a list of
>   paths , use [defaults] inventory=/path/to/file|dir instead. This
>   feature will be  removed in version 2.8. Deprecation warnings can be
>   disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
>
> PLAY [simpletest]
>
> ---
>
> TASK [get facts]
>   ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************** fatal: [cor-001]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "junos-eznc
>   (aka PyEZ) >= 2.1.7 is required for this module. However, junos-eznc
>   does not appear to be currently installed. See
>   https://github.com/Juniper/py-junos-eznc#installation for details on
>   installing junos-eznc."}  to retry, use: --limit
>   @/Users/farhad.kamran/simpletest.retry
>
> PLAY RECAP
>   ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ cor-001 : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

```
MCBOOK:~ user2018$ python

Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 12:01:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import jnpr.junos

jnpr.junos.__version__

'2.1.8dev1'
```

Answer (score 0):

> "junos-eznc (aka PyEZ) >= 2.1.7 is required for this module

Try installing  2.1.7 version. As i can see you have 2.1.8dev1...

Maybe its incompatible with your environment or dependencies...